# Decorator design pattern vs. inheritance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've read the [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) from Wikipedia, and code example from [this site](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/decorator.html).

I see the point that traditional inheritance follows an 'is-a' pattern whereas decorator follows a 'has-a' pattern. And the calling convention of decorator looks like a 'skin' over 'skin' .. over 'core'. e.g.

```
I* anXYZ = new Z( new Y( new X( new A ) ) );
```

as demonstrated in above code example link.

However there are still a couple of questions that I do not understand:

1. what does wiki mean by 'The decorator pattern can be used to extend (decorate) the functionality of a certain object **at run-time**'? the 'new ...(new... (new...))' is a run-time call and is good but a 'AwithXYZ  anXYZ;' is a inheritance at compile time and is bad?
2. from the code example link I can see that the **number of class definition** is almost the same in both implementations. I recall in some other design pattern books like 'Head first design patterns'. They use starbuzz coffee as example and say traditional inheritance will cause a **'class explosion'** because for each combination of coffee, you would come up with a class for it.

   But isn't it the same for decorator in this case? If a decorator class can take ANY abstract class and decorate it, then I guess it does prevent explosion, but from the code example, you have exact # of class definitions, no less...

Would anyone explain?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Let's take some abstract streams for example and imagine you want to provide encryption and compression services over them.

With decorator you have (pseudo code):

```
Stream plain = Stream();
Stream encrypted = EncryptedStream(Stream());
Stream zipped = ZippedStream(Stream());
Stream encryptedZipped = EncryptedStream(ZippedStream(Stream());
// let's ignore the fact that zipping an encrypted string makes no sense :)
Stream zippedEncrypted = ZippedStream(EncryptedStream(Stream());
```

With inheritance, you have:

```
class Stream() {...}
class EncryptedStream() : Stream {...}
class ZippedStream() : Stream {...}
class ZippedEncryptedStream() : EncryptedStream {...}
class EncryptedZippedStream() : ZippedStream {...}
```

1. with decorator, you combine the functionality at runtime, depending on your needs. Each class only takes care of one facet of functionality (compression, encryption, ...)
2. in this simple example, we have 3 classes with decorators, and 5 with inheritance. Now let's add some more services, e.g. filtering and clipping. With decorator you need just 2 more classes to support all possible scenarios and combinations, e.g.  filtering -> clipping -> compression -> encryption.
   With inheritance, you would have to provide a class for each combination - more than 60 classes.

Comment: Thanks Zdeslav. A great explanation on how decorator is used and not causing explosion!

Comment: very nice answer!! really nice

Comment: We could argue that zipping an encrypted stream is not a good idea, but that was not the point of this post wasn't it. Great Answer.

Answer (score 8):

In reverse order:

2) With, say, 10 different *independent* extensions, any combination of which might be needed at run time, 10 decorator classes will do the job. To cover all possibilities by inheritance you'd need *1024* subclasses. And there'd be no way of getting around massive code redundancy.

1) Imagine you had those 1024 subclasses to choose from at run time. Try to sketch out the code that would be needed. Bear in mind that you might not be able to dictate the order in which options are picked or rejected. Also remember that you might have to use an instance for a while before extending it. Go ahead, try. Doing it with decorators is trivial by comparison.

Comment: *1023, in case the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that they can be very similar at times. The applicability and benefits of either solution will depend on your situation.

Others have beat me to adequate answers to your second question.  In short it is that you can combine decorators to achieve more combinations which you cannot do with inheritance.

As such I focus on the first:

You cannot strictly say compile-time is bad and run-time is good, it is just different flexibility.  The ability to change things at run-time can be important for some projects because it allows changes without recompilation which can be slow and requires you be in an environment where you can compile.

An example where you cannot use inheritance, is when you want to add functionality to an instantiated object.  Suppose you are provided an instance of an object that implements a logging interface:

```
public interface ILog{
    //Writes string to log
    public void Write( string message );
}
```

Now suppose you begin a complicated task that involves many objects and each of them does logging so you pass along the logging object.  However you want every message from the task to be prefixed with the task Name and Task Id.  You could pass around a function, or pass along the Name and Id and trust every caller to follow the rule of pre-pending that information, or you could decorate the logging object before passing it along and not have to worry about the other objects doing it right

```
public class PrependLogDecorator : ILog{

     ILog decorated;

     public PrependLogDecorator( ILog toDecorate, string messagePrefix ){
        this.decorated = toDecorate;
        this.prefix = messagePrefix;
     }

     public void Write( string message ){
        decorated.Write( prefix + message );
     }
}
```

Sorry about the C# code but I think it will still communicate the ideas to someone who knows C++

Comment: Thanks vossad01. Your remarks on 'add functionality to an instantiated object' is really good!

Comment: +1 for "An example where you cannot use inheritance, is when you want to add functionality to an instantiated object. "

Answer (score 1):

To address the second part of your question (which might in turn address your first part), using the decorator method you have access to the same number of combinations, but *don't have to write them*.  If you have 3 layers of decorators with 5 options at each level, you have `5*5*5` possible classes to define using inheritance.  Using the decorator method you need 15.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm a C# person and haven't dealt with C++ in a while, but hopefully you get where I'm coming from.

A good example that comes to mind is a `DbRepository` and a `CachingDbRepository`:

```
public interface IRepository {
  object GetStuff();
}

public class DbRepository : IRepository {

  public object GetStuff() {
    //do something against the database
  }
}

public class CachingDbRepository : IRepository {
  public CachingDbRepository(IRepository repo){ }

  public object GetStuff() {
    //check the cache first
    if(its_not_there) {
      repo.GetStuff();
    }
}
```

So, if I just used inheritance, I'd have a `DbRepository` and a `CachingDbRepository`.  The `DbRepository` would query from a database; the `CachingDbRepository` would check its cache and if the data wasn't there, it would query a database.  So there's a possible duplicate implementation here.

By using the decorator pattern, I still have the same number of classes, but my `CachingDbRepository` takes in a `IRepository` and calls its `GetStuff()` to get the data from the underlying repo if it's not in the cache.

So the number of classes are the same, but the use of the classes are related.  `CachingDbRepo` calls the Repo that was passed into it...so it's more like composition over inheritance.

I find it subjective when to decide when to use just inheritance over decoration.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!